# Bottom sheet content not "sticking" to top on show

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I have tried following the [official bottom sheet documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md) to use it. However, I'm left with a very frustrating issue that as you can see from screenshot 1 that the start of the content and the top of the actual bottomsheet has quite some space in between. When I scroll up to show all contents the content "sticks" to the top of the bottom sheet, and then it's okay. See screenshot 2. How do I fix this?

`bottomsheet_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  android:id="@+id/coordinator"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/clBottomSheet"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
        android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_qr_code_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/section_header_style"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_code_button"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drag_handle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/drag_handle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
      
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_button_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bottom_sheet_title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_qr_help_close_button_content_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/drag_handle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/readid_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/readid_margin_small"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/text_style"
        android:padding="@dimen/readid_margin"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_help_body_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_sheet_title"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_title"/>
      
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_title_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/section_header_style"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_help_title_2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_no_qr_help_body_1"/>
      
      
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/text_style"
        android:padding="@dimen/readid_margin"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_help_body_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_title_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_no_qr_help_title_2"/>
      
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_title_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/section_header_style"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_help_title_3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_no_qr_help_body_2"/>
      
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_body_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/text_style"
        android:padding="@dimen/readid_margin"
        android:text="@string/no_qr_help_body_3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_no_qr_help_title_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_no_qr_help_title_3"/>
      
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In code call after clicking a button to show the bottom sheet:

```
private fun showNoQrCodeBottomSheet(context: Context) {
    val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(context)
    bottomSheet.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_layout)
    bottomSheet.show()

    val button = bottomSheet.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.bottom_sheet_button_close)
    button?.setOnClickListener {
        bottomSheet.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Screenshot 1:
[image: screenshot 1 bottom sheet]

Screenshot 2:
[image: screenshot 2 bottom sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove this line:-

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

From your Frame Layout and place this line in you parent layout `CoordinatorLayout`

I hope this will help you!!

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks. The official docs are wrong then, because it said to apply behavior to direct child of coordinator layout.